# Fail2Ban Regex - NGNIX - Custom Regex

Tags: regular-expression, fail2ban

I am trying to create a custom log file for fail2ban NGNIX logs to catch a specific event.  Regex is still relatively new to me so im trying to improve. This will be put into a custom filter but for now I will get using fail2ban-regex

Here is an example of the log

```
1.1.1.1 - - [05/Feb/2021:11:19:48 +0000] "GET /images.php?id=bXlzcWwgLS11c2VyPWFuZ2VscyAtLXBhc3N3b3JkPXNjb690ZXJzCg== HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

I really just want to match on "bXlzcWwg" as it remains consistent I believe it should look similar to this.

```
^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg
```

running a test seems to fine the entry but provides an error.

```
sudo fail2ban-regex "^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg" /var/log/nginx/access.log 

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /var/log/nginx/access.log
Wrong config file: File contains no section headers.
file: '/var/log/nginx/access.log', line: 1
'192.168.6.254 - - [05/Feb/2021:10:54:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 241 "-" "curl/7.58.0"\n'
ERROR: failed to load filter /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

I know the date format is supported from testing.

sudo fail2ban-regex "05/Feb/2021:11:33:25 +0000"

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : <HOST>
Use      single line : 05/Feb/2021:11:33:25 +0000


    Results
    =======
    Failregex: 0 total
    Ignoreregex: 0 total
    Date template hits:
    |- [# of hits] date format
    |  [1] {^LN-BEG}Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
    `-
    Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
    [processed in 0.01 sec]
    |- Missed line(s):
    |  05/Feb/2021:11:33:25 +0000
```

Comment: Elementary mistake. the check regex command is reversed "sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log "^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg" is correct usage and now seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log "^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg"

Regex and log options were reversed..

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg
Use         log file : /var/log/nginx/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 268 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [268] ^<HOST>.*bXlzcWwg
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [841] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 841 lines, 0 ignored, 268 matched, 573 missed
[processed in 0.06 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 573 lines
```

At this post might help someone else banging their head against the wall.